# MySQL Query not selecting all rows

Tags: mysql

I am having a problem with the following query.  Rows from s1_pm_po_item that do not have a value for s1_pm_po_item.CostCode are not selected.  What am i missing here?

```
SELECT s1_pm_po_item.id, s1_pm_costcode.CostCode AS CostCode, s1_pm_po_item.description AS Description, CONCAT( s1_pm_po_item.QtyOrdered, s1_pm_po_item_units.description ) AS QtyOrdered, FORMAT( s1_pm_po_item.UnitPrice, 2 ) AS UnitPrice, FORMAT( QtyOrdered * UnitPrice, 2 ) AS Amount
FROM s1_pm_po_item
INNER JOIN s1_pm_budget_class ON s1_pm_budget_class.id = s1_pm_po_item.CostCode
INNER JOIN s1_pm_budget_item ON s1_pm_budget_item.id = s1_pm_budget_class.BudgetItem
INNER JOIN s1_pm_costcode ON s1_pm_costcode.id = s1_pm_budget_item.CostCode
INNER JOIN s1_pm_po_item_units ON s1_pm_po_item_units.id = s1_pm_po_item.QtyUnit
WHERE s1_pm_po_item.POID =924
```

Comment: Use `LEFT JOIN` in the first `JOIN` statement.

Comment: If they don't have a `CostCode` then this join will fail: `INNER JOIN s1_pm_budget_class ON s1_pm_budget_class.id = s1_pm_po_item.CostCode`. Change these to `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead and rerun.

Comment: Great!  LEFT OUTER JOIN worked.  Thank you.